# Struct memory limit

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have a question about struct in C++. Actually, my code was something like this

```
struct SegmentTree {
    int segmentTree[2500000];

    some functions...
}
```

When I compiled it, it was giving me a segmentation fault immediately, but when I tried to do the same thing with class, everything worked well. So, my question: Is there some limited number of variables that I can use in a struct, or else, what's the problem?

Comment: That's not the only difference. Maybe you once allocated it dynamically, and the other time it was an automatic variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array declared like this will be allocated on the stack(same as with local variables for functions). The limit of the number of elements in a static array is defined by your stack size(which can be modified using compiler options). Consider using dynamically allocated array(or even better `std::vector`) to make use of the heap instead.